# Trouble with JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to using Javascript objects, and can't explain why this isn't working despite my best efforts. Any help is appreciated. I am posting the whole file, because it is extremely small. Thanks again.

```
    <h1 id="mainHeading">
        Testing Objects in Javascript
    </h1>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="inputBox" type="number">
    <div id="response">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var input = document.getElementById('inputBox');
        var mainObj = {
            keys: [],
            numCheck: function () {
                if(input.value >= 0 && input.value < 100) {
                    response.innerHTML = "Avg";
                }
            },

            tracksKey: function (e) {
                code = e.keyCode;
                keys[code] = (e.type === "keydown");
                checksKey();
            },

            checksKey: function () {
                if (keys[13]) {
                    mainObj.numCheck();
                }
            },
        }

        window.addEventListener("keydown", mainObj.tracksKey);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", mainObj.tracksKey)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Write down what you try to achieve with the object.
Obviously, you want to access a property called `keys`. So, since it is a property of your `mainObj` [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), you can it using `mainObj.keys` instead of just `keys`. If you wonder where [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in `tracksKey` points to on runtime: It is the `window` and not `mainObj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keys` and `checksKey` are not global, you have to prefix them with the object they belong to.
Variable `response` is not defined.

```
var response = document.getElementById('response');


tracksKey: function (e) {
  var code = e.keyCode;
  mainObj.keys[code] = (e.type === "keydown");
  mainObj.checksKey();
},
checksKey: function () {
  if (mainObj.keys[13]) {
    mainObj.numCheck();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple that would be an easy fix. So I'm assuming that I will have to add  `mainObj.whatever` for any variable that is inside that object?